# Django models with variable number of fields

Tags: django, models, emailfield

I'm working on a new project and I'd like to create a django model that will have a variable number of `EmailField`s depending on another variable. What I'm trying to create is a House model that has all the members of the house in it (more specifically, their email addresses). Seeing as not all houses are the same size some will have more members than others.

I'd like the user to enter the number of members in their house and have django create an according number of `EmailField`s on the model. Is there any easy way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because Django's model fields are directly linked to fields in a table in the database, a variable number of fields isn't possible. Instead, have another table with a foreign key:

```
class House(models.Model):
    # normal house fields go here

class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='email_addresses')
```

Now you can access all the emails related to a house by using:

```
house = House.objects.get(pk=1)
house.email_addresses.all()
```

The `ForeignKey` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

No. Put the emails in a separate model and link them back to House with a ForeignKey.